# State not being set by setState method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

I am using React JS.

Here is my React class:

```
class SomeClass extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            passAccount: {
                email: "Email"
            },
            errorMessage: ''
        };
    }


    submitRequest = (event) =>{
        //this.state.passAccount.email === 'Email' ? this.setState({errorMessage:'Please enter a valid email'}) : axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/otp/generate-passcode/${this.state.passAccount.email.toString()}`, this.state.passAccount)
        axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/generate/${String(this.state.passAccount.email)}`)
            .then((response) => {
                let result = response.data;
            }).catch((error) =>{
                this.setState({errorMessage: ''});
            });

        console.log(`submitRequest email: `, this.state.passAccount.email);
    }

    handleChange = (event) =>{
        console.log(`input detected`);
        let request = this.state.passAccount;
        let requestValue  = event.target.value;
        this.setState({passAccount: requestValue});
     }

     render() {
            return (
                <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                
                    <Form.Group>
                        <Form.Label>Email Address</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control type="text" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Enter Email Address" style={{width: '25rem'}}/>
                    </Form.Group>



                    <Button type="submit" onClick={() => this.submitRequest()}>Get OTP</Button>
                    <Button type="submit">Sign In</Button>
                </Form>
            );
        }
}


export default SomeClass;
```

In Chrome console, this is what I am getting:

> input detected

> submitRequest email:  Email   //here is what I want to fix

> Form Submitted Successfully

My question is:

In the line where it says in the console:

**submitRequest email:  Email**   //here is what I want to fix, for some reason the setState method is not working what is the reason behind that ?

Is the error in the handleChange method or in the submitRequest method ? what is a possible fix ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you `this.setState({passAccount: requestValue});` you are setting `passAccount` to current value edited in form. But `passAccount` is an object with `email` property.

So I would suggest to modify your code in this way:

```
 handleChange = (event) =>{
    console.log(`input detected`);
    let request = Object.assign({}, this.state.passAccount); // copy this.state.passAccount into request 
    request.email = event.target.value; // change request email
    this.setState({ passAccount: request }); // set passAccount
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared your state variable **passAccount** as an object which contains an **email** property. If you want to update this **email** property then in your **handleChange** function, you need to update the state like this:

```
this.setState({ passAccount: { email: requestValue });
```